# Plotly Bar Chart Not Reflecting Values in Call

Tags: python, plotly, python-polars

This is driving me nutz.

I have a Polars dataframe named `totals` that stores counts by year:

[image: dataframe screen shot]

I'm making a very simple bar chat in plotly with code like the following:

```
px.bar(
    totals.to_pandas(),
    x = 'commit_year',
    y = 'count',
    color='commit_year'
)
```

This returns...

[image: example of graph rendered]

I don't understand why I'm not seeing bars for each year matching the totals from the dataframe.

I set the y axis to a list of 12 random numbers to see how it affected the chart:

```
px.bar(
    totals.to_pandas(),
    x = 'commit_year',
    y = [22, 33, 231, 33, 31, 31, 23, 12, 13, 10, 33, 44],
    color='commit_year'
)
```

This look great.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

The value returned by the following...

```
totals.select('count').to_series()
```

Is as follows:

u32
73
93
88
6
21
439
365
91
55
36
31
1

Comment: I tried the first code in my environment and the bar graph was displayed correctly. My environment is plotly:5.13.0, polars:0.14.27, jupyterlab:3.4.6. I also ran the following code and got the same results. `px.bar(totals.to_pandas(), x = totals['commit_year'], y = totals['count'], color='commit_year')`

Comment: try casting count to int32.  I wonder if pandas and/or plotly can't handle unsigned integers.

Comment: Converting to int32 gave the same result and the graph was drawn correctly. The internal structure was also converted to int64 for the x-axis.

Comment: I think you need to remove the `color=commit_year` argument

Comment: @r-beginners I meant for Adam to do that.